# Need help in hiding slack API token in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I am using Slack API token in Google App script and calling in the hard coded API token which needs to be hidden in the script. Any idea on how I can hide it or store and then call it?

Example:-

var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(GET_USER_ID_FROM_EMAILID_ENDPOINT, {
method             : 'get',
contentType        : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
headers            : {
***Authorization : 'Bearer ' + 'xoxb-181.....' // Token to be hidden or stored***
},
payload            : JSON.stringify(payload),
muteHttpExceptions : true,
})

Comment: Have you looked at properties service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing API keys and secrets in Google AppScript user property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540618/storing-api-keys-and-secrets-in-google-appscript-user-property)